# Failure in pattern matching in Agda 2.5.1.2

Tags: pattern-matching, agda

Given the following datatype which encodes a verified comparison between two natural numbers:

```
open import Agda.Builtin.Nat

data Compare : Nat -> Nat -> Set where
  LT : {m : Nat} {n : Nat} -> Compare m (suc (m + n))
  EQ : {m : Nat} -> Compare m m
  GT : {m : Nat} {n : Nat} -> Compare (suc (m + n)) m
```

the following code correctly compares numbers and computes their difference:

```
comparehelper : {m : Nat} {n : Nat} -> (Compare m n) -> Compare (suc m) (suc n)
comparehelper LT = LT
comparehelper EQ = EQ
comparehelper GT = GT

compare : (m : Nat) (n : Nat) -> Compare m n
compare 0 0 = EQ
compare (suc _) 0 = GT
compare 0 (suc _) = LT
compare (suc m) (suc n) = comparehelper (compare m n)

differencehelper : {m : Nat} {n : Nat} -> (Compare m n) -> Nat
differencehelper (LT {n = difflt1}) = suc difflt1
differencehelper EQ = 0
differencehelper (GT {n = difflt1}) = suc difflt1

difference : Nat -> Nat -> Nat
difference m n = differencehelper (compare m n)
```

but the following, apparently functionally identical, code does not (the
pattern matching fails type checking):

```
compare' : (m : Nat) (n : Nat) -> Compare m n
compare' 0 0 = EQ
compare' (suc _) 0 = GT
compare' 0 (suc _) = LT
compare' (suc m) (suc n) with compare' m n
... | LT = LT
... | EQ = EQ
... | GT = GT

difference' : Nat -> Nat -> Nat
difference' m n with compare' m n
... | LT {n = difflt1} = suc difflt1
... | EQ = 0
... | GT {n = difflt1} = suc difflt1
```

What is the explanation for the difference in behavior?  As stated in the question, I am running Agda 2.5.1.2.

Comment: Your example type-checks with the current development version (Agda 2.5.2-017c22e).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that pattern-matching on a value of type `Compare m n` refines the patterns for `m` and `n`.

So the scheme `compare' (suc m) (suc n)` which `...` stands for is not valid anymore. You have to repeat the left hand side with refined patterns e.g.

```
compare' (suc m) (suc n) with compare' m n
compare' (suc m) (suc .(suc m + _)) | LT = LT
compare' (suc m) (suc .m)           | EQ = EQ
compare' (suc .(suc m + _)) (suc m) | GT = GT
```

I have used underscores here for the variables which are in scope but not explicitly named (they are implicit arguments to `LT` and `GT` respectively). The fact that they are not named but required in the patterns can be a good clue that they should maybe be explicit arguments of the `LT` and `GT` constructors.

Alternatively, if you don't care about the patterns, you can use underscores (which may stand for *any* pattern including dotted ones) and write:

```
compare' (suc _) (suc _) | LT = LT
compare' (suc _) (suc _) | EQ = EQ
compare' (suc _) (suc _) | GT = GT
```

As @asr mentioned newer versions of Agda will support your current pattern-match because [dot patterns have been made optional](https://github.com/agda/agda/blob/master/doc/release-notes/2-5-2.md#language).